# Write text file now crashes, previously OK

Tags: android

My app has worked fine for years and was updated for SDK26 earlier this year and still worked. It no longer does and stops when trying to write to a text file. This code has not changed for years so I am puzzled. I am now working in Android studio 3.1.3.
The code crashes giving debug;
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick.
The user clicks and, if the data checks are OK, it writes to a text file.

The write file source is;

```
try { 
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("ansi360.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);                     
        out.write(mCode+",");
        out.write(mUnits+","); 
        etc...
    // close the file 
        out.close(); 
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The first line causes the error.
View.java says 'Source code  does not match bytecode

I am wondering if a recent update either of Android or the phone's system now requires write permissions. This is a small txt file which would be written to the on board storage rather than to an SD card.

I wrote this 7 years ago as a means of learning Android, but haven't used android since so I am essentially a beginner. Looking online is seems that this method should still work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the rest of that stacktrace? If this was a project from 7 years ago, I suspect you aren't requesting the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Thanks. Not only that. The MODE_WORLD_READABLE has been deprecated. Using MODE_PRIVATE fixes it. SOLVED